# Warum heißt es „ihrer“ und nicht „ihren“?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, genitive, possessive-pronoun

> Gibt es **in einer ihrer Familien** eine interessante Person wie Mark?

Der **Dativ** ist der Fall und es müsste **ihren** anstatt **ihrer** sein, weil *Familien* Plural ist, oder?

Übrigens bin ich nur Niveau A2.1, aber ich weiß schon, dass **Genitiv** ein Fall ist.

Comment: The same comments on the spelling again ^^ The beginning of sentences, names and nouns are capitalized in German. And there are no spaces before punctuation characters! The use of an proofreading software e.g., https://languagetool.org/ helps to avoid such easy errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence is parsed this way: "in einer (*Dativ*, singular) ihrer (*Genitiv*, plural) Familien".
In English it would be "in one **of their** (or "**of her**"!) families".

Note that "in einer **Ihrer** (capitalized) Familien" means "in one **of your** families".